# How to call a query from MS Access 2010 (.accdb) within VB.Net 2010?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have this code that populates a datagridview with data from ms access:

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection  
Dim ds As New DataSet  
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter  
Dim Sql As String

Sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE case_no=?"  
Try  
  con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Sample.accdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=dbadmin2010"  
    con.Open()  
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Sql, con)  
    da.SelectCommand = cmd  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("case_no", case_no)  

    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet  
    da.Fill(ds, "Case Info")  
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Case Info")  

Catch ex As Exception  
    MsgBox(ex.Message)  
End Try
```

Now I had just finished creating a query from design view within MS Access itself, is there a way to call that query and retrieve the results to my datagridview?

Comment: yes. did you tried? what is the error?

Comment: @spajce, no I haven't tried because I don't know the command to call the query from within MS-Access itself. The code posted in my question is what I am using right now, as you can see, the query is hardcoded from withing vb.net.  What I want to do is I want to call the query I created using design view within MS-Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the query name and set the command type, for example, in addition to what you already have, you can use the following notes:

```
Try
    con.ConnectionString = enter_connection_string_here 
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = "NameOfQuery"
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("case_no", case_no)

    da.Fill(ds, "Case Info")
```

Comment: How can the above be modified so you can pass criteria into the stored query?